# Error while loading .ods sheet into Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, openoffice-calc, ods

I am trying to read a column of integers in a spreadsheet into Octave using the code

```
A = odsread('Data.ods', 'Sheet1', 'A1:A946');
```

But it fails and I get a message with warnings and errors as :

> ```
> > unzip:  cannot find or open Data.ods, Data.ods.zip or Data.ods.ZIP.
> file Data.ods couldn't be unpacked. Is it the proper file format?
> warning: UnZip failed with error 9
> Output:
> error: warning: STATE structure must have fields 'identifier' and 'state'
> error: called from
>     __OCT_spsh_open__ at line 72 column 7
>     odsopen at line 267 column 30
>     odsread at line 179 column 7
> ```

So the error says that "STATE structure must have fields 'identifier' and 'state'" , what does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the full path to the file should be included to make it work. It cannot load the file itself even when the file is in the same directory.

Comment: I have to say I cannot reproduce this. Would you mind specifying octave version, io package version, operating system, and interface used?

Comment: (oh, nevermind about the interface, I can see this is OCT from the error message)